No network connection via LAN
I am using kubuntu 22.04 and today I moved some items in my home office.
My PC has a LAN cable connection to a netgear switch, which is connected to my internet router/modem thingy.
After I moved my stuff I tested all my pc gear and everything works except my internet connection. I checked the plugged in cables PC <-> switch <-> router. When I do a ping to an external address I get something along the line "network not reachable". At my switch both LED are green and not blinking.
If I plug the LAN cable out and in again on my PC one green LED is active and a yellow one is blinking then goes black again, but still no network connection.
My printer, which is connected via the same switch is reachable.
What do the active LEDs mean? What can I do to check where my problem lies?
I already tried a different LAN cable and a different port on the switch, but the same behaviour exists.
I already had that problem sometimes in the past, but it did go away on its own

Power cycle the router and switch (and PC). Have a cup of tea while they reset. Then see if you still have the problem. If so, then try a different port in the switch. Swap cables to check that all are still good.

I did all that. The printer, which also is connected to the switch is available from other PCs in my network. The other PCs can reach the internet via the router.  Had so far several cups of tea ( always a good advice!) Swapped the cable and the ports.
I suspect my LAN connector on my PC is wonky, but before I buy new hardware I wand to make sure nothing else is amiss.
